# how to get access to resultset or using rowcallbackhandler when using SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: spring, spring-data

I need to write a generic code which can call any given stored procedure and handle the parameters type automatically using meta data and that's the reason I am using SimpleJdbcCall with MapSqlParameterSource.

The issue is with that the data I am getting back is a List of Maps, but the result set can be huge, I need to have access to the resultset directly or any other way in which I won't be having the entire List of Maps in memory but flushing the records to a stream as soon as the resultset is moved to next record.

Comment: Just had a look at StoredProcedureItemReader from Spring Batch, it allows streaming of resultset, but here the issue will be with use of meta data for parameters (procedure column meta data) automatically as can be done with SimpleJdbcCall

Answer (score 0):

The method [`SimpleJdbcCall.returningResultSet()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#returningResultSet%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29) allows you to register a [`RowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) to handle ResultSets one row at a time.